# How to Enter angularJs Array to MySQL Database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have this function with array object that has all the Cart Orders

```
createMyOrder: function (myOrder, callback, err) {
            var data = myOrder;

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            return $http({
                url: jsonurl + 'cRtOrder',
                method: "POST",
                data: data
            }).success(callback).error(err);
        },
```

This is what `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` shows.

```
[{"cart_item_id":"94","cart_item_image":"super-foods-400x400.jpg","cart_item_name":"Chicken Comma","cart_item_price":"77","cart_item_qty":1},{"cart_item_id":"89","cart_item_image":"nachos10.jpg","cart_item_name":"Rice with fish","cart_item_price":"9.87","cart_item_qty":1}]
```

How can I send this array to the database using MySQL? Using

```
//Repetitive Insert command on each row
```

or

```
//Single Insert command by concatenating all array values into array
```

I'm using AngularJs with PHP and mySQL. I have already done the validations. The only thing left to do is to insert the array to the mySQL Database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert json string to php array in your php file:

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
```

After that you could use a foreach to iterate your array:

```
foreach($obj as $item){
  echo $item['cart_item_id'];
}
```

Where i wrote the echo you must insert in the database with the cells you want

Comment: This is what I did earlier `public function createMyOrder()
    {   

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $cart_item_id = $data['cart_item_id'];
        $cart_item_image = $data['cart_item_image'];
        $cart_item_name = $data['cart_item_name'];
        $cart_item_price = $data['cart_item_price'];
        $cart_item_qty = $data['cart_item_qty'];

        console.log($data);
               
        if (empty($data)) {
            $data['message'] = 0;
        }`

Comment: You didn't  do it, I put  a foreach and you don't wrote one . You have two elements, you need a foreach. In this code you don't have it.  My answer is correctly, you should try it. If you don't understand me just tell me

Comment: I don't understand how that works i have tried it. I have also used the foreach, i don't know what i'm missing here?

Comment: Thank You so Much, now I have Understood. and made it worked :) Thank you.